# Is dropping duplicates faster when adding the partition to the subset

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider a table that has transaction ids and transaction dates.

The table is partitions by the dates.

Is it faster to perform a drop duplicate on just the ids or both the ids and the date?

That is to say, which is faster:

- `df.dropDuplicates(subset=['tran_id'])` or
- `df.dropDuplicates(subset=['tran_id', 'tran_date'])`

Comment: The date would presumably allow Spark to identify the correct partition.  You could run a test and see which is faster.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, do you know how to run speed tests in Spark?

Comment: We have time method in SparkSession class, but it's applicable only for scala. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html#time[T](f:=%3ET):T